# HTML5 JS play same sound multiple times at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm create a very basic HTML5 game and I've hit a little wall, basically I have an array, this array is populated with one sound file (it is an array so I can assign more sounds if needed)

```
this.Sounds["L_Explosion1"] = new Audio("Assets/Sounds/Explosion_1.wav");
this.Sounds["L_Explosion1"].volume = 1;
this.Sounds["L_Explosion1"].load();
```

When the player presses the space bar I want to play the sound so I run this code

```
this.Sounds["L_Explosion1"].play();
```

however if I press space bar again before the sound played it will not play it, what I am trying to do is play the same sound multiple times event if the same has not yet finished, how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In order to play multiple instances of the sound at the same time, you will need to create a new copy of that `Audio` element. One way to do this is to use the `.cloneNode()` method and play the cloned audio every time the spacebar is pressed.

```
this.Sounds["L_Explosion1"].cloneNode(true).play();
```

Comment: This works correctly, but you do need to provide a parameter in cloneNode( true or false ) http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_clonenode.asp

Comment: That link points to the XML DOM .cloneNode() method, which does require the argument. But for the HTML DOM .cloneNode(), the argument is optional. See: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_clonenode.asp

However, Firefox recently switched the default for the optional argument in their .cloneNode() implementation, so the safe thing to do would be to always provide the argument when using .cloneNode(). See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode

Comment: will this copy the sound each time you press spacebar ? Is there a way to clean sounds ? or delete node on('ended') ?

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 audio element has many limitations and it's not well suited for a complex audio use-case like what you are describing, which seems to be a game.

Instead, consider using the [WebAudio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API). You'll have to:

- Use a [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to load your audio file in a buffer
- Assign that buffer to a [`AudioBufferSourceNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode) instance.
- Connect that node to the appropriate destination or intermediate nodes (e.g. [`GainNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GainNode)).
- If you also need to stop sounds, you'll need to keep track of each source node that is created and that hasn't finished playing yet, which can be done by listen to the source node's [`onended`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioScheduledSourceNode/ended_event).

Here's a class that encapsulates the logic to load a sound from a URL and play/stop it as many times as you want, keeping track of all currently playing sources and cleaning them up as needed:

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

const context = new AudioContext();

export class Sound {

    url = '';

    buffer = null;

    sources = [];

    constructor(url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    load() {
        if (!this.url) return Promise.reject(new Error('Missing or invalid URL: ', this.url));

        if (this.buffer) return Promise.resolve(this.buffer);

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

            request.open('GET', this.url, true);
            request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

            // Decode asynchronously:

            request.onload = () => {
                context.decodeAudioData(request.response, (buffer) => {
                    if (!buffer) {
                        console.log(`Sound decoding error: ${ this.url }`);

                        reject(new Error(`Sound decoding error: ${ this.url }`));

                        return;
                    }

                    this.buffer = buffer;

                    resolve(buffer);
                });
            };

            request.onerror = (err) => {
                console.log('Sound XMLHttpRequest error:', err);

                reject(err);
            };

            request.send();
        });
    }

    play(volume = 1, time = 0) {
        if (!this.buffer) return;

        // Create a new sound source and assign it the loaded sound's buffer:

        const source = context.createBufferSource();

        source.buffer = this.buffer;

        // Keep track of all sources created, and stop tracking them once they finish playing:

        const insertedAt = this.sources.push(source) - 1;

        source.onended = () => {
            source.stop(0);

            this.sources.splice(insertedAt, 1);
        };

        // Create a gain node with the desired volume:

        const gainNode = context.createGain();

        gainNode.gain.value = volume;

        // Connect nodes:

        source.connect(gainNode).connect(context.destination);

        // Start playing at the desired time:

        source.start(time);
    }

    stop() {
        // Stop any sources still playing:

        this.sources.forEach((source) => {
            source.stop(0);
        });

        this.sources = [];
    }

}
```

You can then do something like this:

```
const soundOne = new Sound('./sounds/sound-one.mp3')
const soundTwo = new Sound('./sounds/sound-two.mp3')

Promises.all([
  soundOne.load(),
  soundTwo.load(),
]).then(() => {
  buttonOne.onclick = () => soundOne.play();
  buttonTwo.onclick = () => soundOne.play();
})
```