# Playing the same html audio multiple times before it ends

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, html5-audio

I have a bunch of audio tags in my html, and was looking for a way to play the same sound multiple times.
If a sound is still playing it cannot be triggered again.
I ended up making multiple tags for the same 2s sound bite, putting them in an array and cycling through them:

```
var sounds = [hit,hit2,hit3,hit4,hit5];

////////////

private soundIndex = 0
public playSoundFromArray(soundArray){
        if (this.soundIndex == soundArray.length -1){
            this.soundIndex = 0
        }
        else this.soundIndex++
        soundArray[this.soundIndex].play();
    }
```

That worked fairly well.
Just after I'd finished that, I found a post dealing with the issue:
[HTML5 JS play same sound multiple times at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654558)

The voted answer there was advising making and playing a clone of the audio every time:

```
sound.cloneNode(true).play();
```

This is great, and doesn't require any additional audio tags.
It just felt a bit weird cloning nodes potentially hundreds of times, every time a sound is played. Is there any reason not to use this? Would the mass cloning affect the memory at all if they are not being saved as variables?

Comment: what about [`loop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/loop) attribute

Comment: @bigless loop will begin the audio again when it reaches the end, but I'm trying to play it multiple times BEFORE it finishes.